# Qt Check platform type : Mobile or Desktop

Tags: android, c++, ios, linux, qt

I'm looking for some code I could use to check if my application is executed on a mobile/tablet or a computer. Here is a sample to explain what I'm doing :

```
#include <QtGlobal>

#if defined Q_OS_BLACKBERRY || defined Q_OS_ANDROID || defined Q_OS_IOS || defined Q_OS_WP
#define Q_OS_MOBILE
#else
#define Q_OS_DESKTOP
#endif
```

How does it look to you? Am I reinventing the wheel?

Comment: that is the way to go :)

Comment: Depending on your needs it may be enough to check screen resolution QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry()

Answer (score 1):

The reason there's no (to my knowledge) pre-fabbed #defines for this is the definition of mobile vs desktop vs embedded is blurry. For example Q_OS_QNX is set alongside Q_OS_BLACKBERRY, and Q_OS_DARWIN is set on both Q_OS_IOS and Q_OS_MACX. Similar problem for Q_OS_LINUX on Android, and then there's a range of confusion around Windows versions.

If the definitions you've suggested work for your use-case, I think that's a perfectly reasonable way to proceed. I maybe would use a different naming scheme to Q_OS_foo however.

Comment: My algorithm works in every situation. I thought about exotic systems such as Darwin and QNX. You can draw some diagrams to make sure it does. By the way, Jolla and Ubuntu Phone were not my targeted platforms.